# Paginated view rerturning "http" urls in previous and next properties

Tags: django-rest-framework, pagination

I have a django rest-framework view that inherits from generics.ListAPIView.

```
class PessoasListAPIView(generics.ListAPIView, CustomGenericAPIView):
    """View que lista os Pessoas com dados completos."""

    serializer_class = PessoasSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        nome = self.request.query_params.get("nome")

        if nome:
            queryset = PessoasModel.objects.filter(nome__contains=nome, status='A')
        else:
             queryset = PessoasModel.objects.all().filter(status='A')

        return queryset
```

The problem is my view always returns an http url for the previous and next properties of the response. How can change it for https?

I've tried adding the following `SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')` to settings.py file. (Chatgpt tip)